# How to activate polystyrene with carboxyl group?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds, reactivity

Is there a simple (that is one that requires few and not very exotic reagents) chemical reaction to "activate" or "functionalize" the polystyrene of a simple microtitre plate?

In other words, I would like to add carboxyl groups to the surface of a common ELISA plate to then use ethyl-carbodiimide hydrochloride and *N*-hydroxysuccinimide to immobilize a target on the bottom of the well.

Comment: These may be useful if you have access https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03602559.2017.1370109?journalCode=lpte20   https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07366578708078821?src=recsys    https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/003238619390483Q

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to nitrate polystyrene powder with nitric & sulfuric acid mixture and reduce the nitro groups to aniline with $\ce{SnCl2/HCl}$ as described in here<sup>1</sup>. How effective this would be for a microtitre plate I cannot say, but chemistry is an experimental subject.

**Reference**

1. Zhao, H. & Guo, J. & Bian, L. & Wei, Z. & Deng, K.. (**2009**). Synthesis of nitro and amino linear polystyrene. Hecheng Shuzhi Ji Suliao/China Synthetic Resin and Plastics. 26. 22-26. ([link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289290871_Synthesis_of_nitro_and_amino_linear_polystyrene))